# Application crashed while loading .so files in android 4.3

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, csip-simple

When I am installing app in android 4.3 device, application got crashed. The reason for crash is loading .so files. but it is working fine in all other devices. Here I am providing my logcat:

```
08-26 15:33:47.207: D/dalvikvm(8278): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.package.name-2/libstlport_shared.so 0x434f4d60

08-26 15:33:47.247: D/houdini(8278): [8278] Loading library(version:
3.4.8a.45022 RELEASE)... successfully.

08-26 15:33:47.277: D/dalvikvm(8278): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.package.name-2/libstlport_shared.so 0x434f4d60

08-26 15:33:47.277: D/dalvikvm(8278): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.package.name-2/libstlport_shared.so 0x434f4d60, skipping init

08-26 15:33:47.277: D/dalvikvm(8278): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.mywu.mywuconnect-2/libmywujni.so 0x434f4d60

08-26 15:33:47.297: A/libc(8278): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 8278 (com.package.name)
```

Comment: Can you post more details about the .so file like if you have a different version for different architectures such as arm,x86 and the device on which you are trying to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the times this problem is depends on the processors also, you already mentioned "working fine in all other devices" in your question. To overcome this problem you should maintain the folders(armeabi, areabi-v7a,x86,mips) the copy the .so files into the respective folders.